# I get WARN: IntentDialog - no intent handler found for null when I fill out a form Node.js Bot framework

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, forms, botframework

I am very new to node.js and the bot framework. I created a form in json which is run in my bot. However after filling out the form I get the error

/ - `WARN: IntentDialog - no intent handler found for null`

I am not sure as to why that is. I am using the .addAttachment to use the card and the session.send(msg) to present the form to the user. However after the form is complete and submitted I get the above error message. Below is the form being used and the code in node.js

```
var card = {
    'contentType': 'application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive',
    'content': {
        '$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
        'type': 'AdaptiveCard',
        'version': '1.0',
        'body': [
            {
                'type': 'Container',
                'items': [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        'actions': [
            // Contact Information Form
            {
                'type': 'Action.ShowCard',
                'title': 'Contact Form',
                'card': {
                    'type': 'AdaptiveCard',
                    'body': [
                        {
                            'type': 'TextBlock',
                            'text': 'Please enter your name:'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'Input.Text',
                            'id': 'name',
                            'speak': '<s>Please enter your name</s>',
                            'placeholder': 'Enter Name',
                            'style': 'text'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'TextBlock',
                            'text': 'What is your phone number?'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'Input.Number',
                            'id': 'phone',
                            //'style': 'text'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'TextBlock',
                            'text': 'What is your email address?'
                        },
                        {
                            'type': 'Input.Text',
                            'id': 'email',
                            'placeholder': 'Enter Email',
                            'style': 'text'
                        }
                    ],
                    'actions': [
                        {
                            'type': 'Action.Submit',
                            'title': 'Submit',
                            'data': {
                                'type': 'submit'
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },

        ]
    }
};
```

code in node.js

```
bot.dialog('Ask for contact info', [
    function (session, args) {
        if (session.conversationData.amending) {
            session.dialogData.nextStep = 'Show summary';
        } else {
            session.dialogData.nextStep = 'Ask for severity';
        }
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Could you please add details of who you’d like us to contact to discuss your bug further?");
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .addAttachment(card);
        session.send(msg);

    },
    function (session, results) {
        session.conversationData.contactInfo = results.response;
        session.beginDialog(session.dialogData.nextStep);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive submit from adaptive card form, you can try to use following waterfall steps:

```
bot.dialog('form', [
    (session, args, next) => {

        var card = {
             ...
        };

        if (session.message && session.message.value) {
            // A Card's Submit Action obj was received

            next(session.message.value)
        } else {
            var msg = new builder.Message(session)
                .addAttachment(card);
            session.send(msg);
        }

    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    }
])
```

However, I cannot reproduce the issue `WARN: IntentDialog - no intent handler found for null`, could you provide your repo for me to have a glance of your whole structure, which is benifit for further analysis.